# Using check-type functions to check the type of a Julia concrete type instance

Tags: types, macros, julia

I created a module called "my_mod" and defined a concrete type "Dy_Model", when designing my macro inside the module with an input argument as "model", I wanted to check whether "model" is in the type of "Dy_Model" inside the macro.
This is what I have tested within "my_mod" environment using a variable "a" (you can ignore the content of the "model"):

```
julia> model
Main.my_mod.Dy_Model(Ipopt.Optimizer, Dict{Symbol, Main.my_mod.Differential_Var_data}(), Dict{Symbol, Main.my_mod.Independent_Var_data}())

julia> a=quote $(esc(model)) end

quote
    #= REPL[70]:1 =#
    $(Expr(:escape, Main.my_mod.Dy_Model(Ipopt.Optimizer, Dict{Symbol, Main.my_mod.Differential_Var_data}(), Dict{Symbol, Main.my_mod.Independent_Var_data}())))
end

julia> typeof(a.args[2].args[1])
Main.my_mod.Dy_Model

#but
julia> typeof(a.args[2].args[1]) == my_mod.Dy_Model
false

julia> a.args[2].args[1] isa my_mod.Dy_Model
false
```

It seems that Julia gave two conflicting result? With the one on the top saying a.args[2].args[1] is the type of Dy_Model, but at the bottom where I wanted to do the check using "isa" and implement it inside my macro, it said the type is not Dy_Model.

May I ask if I missed something?

---

Here is a similar example, the function is called within my macro, both shown at the bottom, after adding the type restriction on the input argument "_model::Dy_Model", it will return

```
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching construct_differential_variable(::Main.my_mod.Dy_Model, ::Vector{Any}) Closest candidates are:construct_differential_variable(::Main.my_mod.Dy_Model, ::Vector) at...
```

even if the argument passed inside the macro is indeed the correct type. If I exclude the "::Dy_Model" it will be fine, but I would like to impose a type check here.

```
function construct_differential_variable(_model::Dy_Model,_info::Vector)

diff_var_data = Differential_Var_data(_info[7],_info[1],_info[2],_info[3],_info[4],_info[5],_info[6])

#assign data of a new differential variable to the model
_model.Differential_var_index[diff_var_data.Run_sym] = diff_var_data

return diff_var_data
```

end

```
macro differential_variable(model,args...)

#...dealing with args 

return :(construct_differential_variable($(esc(model)),$var_info))
```

end

Thank you.

Comment: Macros have no information about the types of variables. What are you planning to use this macro for?

Comment: This macro is for users to input a "Dy_Model" type model and the information of one of the fields of the model. Inside the macro, both the model and the information will be checked first and then the information will be added to the model.

Comment: A macro cannot check the type of an input argument. It can produce code that checks types at runtime, but not at compile time, which is when macros are expanded. It's a bit unclear, but I suspect you are trying to do something which is impossible. Can you show some example code demonstrating what you want?

Comment: I have already updated the code above.